# React <hr /> with dynamically set colors

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to have a `<hr />` in my **react application**. I want to change the color of it in different places? Is there any way of doing it? If we use a functional component to achieve this, how should be do it?

Comment: with props, create a hr component and pass a color prop to it

Comment: [You can set `background-color`, `border-color`, and `color`](https://codesandbox.io/s/vv0m4nxjm7) to the color you like to make it work properly in all browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing special to it really.

```js
const Rule = ({ color }) => (
  <hr
    style={{
      borderColor: color,
    }}
  />
);

const App = () => (
  <div>
    Here's an orange rule. <Rule color="orange" />
    Here's a blue rule. <Rule color="blue" />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("main"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set with below css for that :

```
    hr {
        background-color: red; //or whatever color you want.
        height: 1px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<hr>` element, from my experience, if you're leaving it unstyled beyond a color, is best styled through the CSS rule `border-color`, as in the following example:

```css
.foo { border-color: black; }
```

```html
<hr class="foo" />
```

As for React, you could start with their basic CSS prop and expand it from there.

```
render() {
  let className = 'hr-color';
  if (this.props.isActive) {
    className += ' foo';
  }
  return <hr className={className}/>
}
```